# Vacation time auto calculate using excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

I am creating a spreadsheet for Managed Time Off.  Here is the accrue amount based on years in service:

```
Accrual Periods 40 Hours per Week
0-1.99 years earn 136 hours (5.23 hrs per pay period)
2 – 5 years ear 176 hours (6.77 hrs per pay period)
6 – 10 years ear 208 hours (8 hrs per pay period)
11-15 years earn 248 hours(9.54 hrs per pay period)
16-20 years earn 288 hours (11.08 hrs per pay period)
21 or more years earn 312 hours (12 hrs per pay period)
```

Our pay periods are every 2 weeks.  Our last pay period was 9/3/16 - 9/16/16
Employees are allowed to carryover 1 year of MTO.  Often times they ask how much MTO they need to use by their Anniversary date so they are not above the carryout limit.  I started a spreadsheet but cannot seem to get it to populate correctly.  Does anyone have any suggestions?
This is manual calculation I use.

```
D. Ernzen 
Hire Date: 10/28/1991
MTO/yr = 312 hrs per year
MTO/pay period = 12.0
Carryover allowed on aniv date = 312
Current MTO (as of 9/17/16)      389.5
MTO used 9/17-present day        (20.0)
MTO accruing (9/17-10/28)       + 34.8   
MTO balance on Anniversary      = 404.3
Carryover                      - 312.0
Needs to be used by 10/28       =92.3
```

I would like to keep data entry to a minimum.  The biggest issue I'm having is pay periods til anniv count.  Any suggestions or help is greatly appreciated!  Thank you :)

Comment: what formulas/code have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming cell `A2` contains the hire date then:

Years since hire can be calculated using:

```
=INT((TODAY()-A2)/365.25)
```

Pay periods to anniversary can be calculated using:

```
=INT(26 - MOD((TODAY()-A2),365.25)/14) + 1
```

Accrual rate, max carryover etc. can all easily be found using a `VLookup` based on the years since hire.

Comment: Thanks for the response!  I have used "IF" to auto populate the accrual rate & carryover for each employee.

Comment: Here is the formula I'm using for Work days til anniv date.

Comment: =(C2-D2-1)/14      C is Anniv. date, D is end of last pay period, I subtract 1 because I don't want the actual anniv date included as that is the day the rollover takes place.  Hope this makes sense?  I don't know what the heck I'm doing lol....  I also tried this formula to eliminate weekends             =NETWORKDAYS(D2,C2)/10  and multiply that by a daily rate for 10/12=.83333